# Unable to get loaded extension to work with keydown event with cypress

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-chrome-extension, cypress

My extension commands in `manifest.json` to toggle alert with Ctrl + Shift + X key press combination.

```
 "commands": {
        "toggle_extension": {
            "suggested_key": {
              "default": "Ctrl+Shift+X",
              "mac": "Command+Shift+X"
            },
            "description": "Toggle Your Extension"
          }
    }
```

My dev dependencies:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/chrome": "^0.0.262",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.12",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^12.0.2",
    "cypress": "^13.6.6",
    "ts-loader": "^9.5.1",
    "typescript": "5.3.3",
    "webpack": "^5.90.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4"
  }
```

My test case

```
describe("Test alert", () => {
  it("passes", () => {
    cy.visit("");

    cy.window().trigger('keydown', {
        key: "x", // "X" key code
        keyCode: 88,
        ctrlKey: true,
        shiftKey: true,
      });

    cy.get("#alert").should("exist");
  })
});
```

My `cypress.config.ts`. Extension code in directory called `release`.

```
import { defineConfig } from "cypress";
import * as path from "path";

export default defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    baseUrl: "https://example.com",
    specPattern: "tests/**/*.cy.ts",
    supportFile: false,
    fixturesFolder: false,
    defaultCommandTimeout: 5000,
    viewportWidth: 1280,
    viewportHeight: 720,
    chromeWebSecurity: false,
    testIsolation: true,
    screenshotOnRunFailure: false,
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      on('before:browser:launch', (browser, launchOptions) => {
          launchOptions.extensions.push(path.resolve(__dirname, "release"));
          return launchOptions;
      });
    }
  },
});
```

Running cypress with `npx cypress run --browser chrome --headed` and extension seems to be loaded but test case does not work as expected and alert element never shows up. Am I missing something or attempting something impossible?

Comment: Full code in https://github.com/Tsingis/instagram-pic-enlarger/tree/feat/cypress

Comment: Apparently it sends to the JS `window` of the tab, but you need to send the key to the browser process window, which is usually done using a native API. There are many libraries for that in NPM.

Comment: @Rab.Scarabelli I don't understand alertBox isn't building? Release contains compiled javascript files and everything works fine from that point of view once bundle is done.

Answer (score 2):

If you run the project "build" script, the output code in `./release/alertbox.js` is just this (clearly not capable of displaying any kind of alert)

```js
(()=>{"use strict";new WeakSet})();
```

If you run the "package" script, then look inside the zip file, the alertbox code is the same.

Perhaps the code was compiling previously and something changed, or a dependency is missing from `package.json`.

Comment: Isn't that just how webpack works? Stuff is found in bundled `content.js`.
I deleted _node_modules_ and _release_ folders, did clean `npm install` and webpack build with `npm run build`. Everything works without issues after I also unpack this freshly created extension.